# examples of use of `rbokeh` inside `jupyter-notebook`

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook, rbokeh

Is it possible (and unproblematic) to use `rbokeh` in an `R` cell of a  `jupyter-notebook`?

I was not even able to display the plots inline. Are there examples available online?